# How to use the 3rd party script file in ts component file?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

This is the link for the 3rd party script file [jsfiddle example link](https://jsfiddle.net/kishore0207/e3L2xyo0/7/),  but in that external file is the 3rd party js script file it having the all functions are self-invoked functions.

> How can I declare that function in the ts file?

After declaring the variable in ts file, I need to call the below 3rd party function.

```
affirm.checkout.open({
     success: function (card_details) {
       console.log('#### calling affirm.checkout.open');
     },
     error: function (error_response) {
       console.log('#### calling affirm.checkout.open Error =======');
     },
     checkout_data: ObjectData;
   });
```

While am running the application getting the `ERROR in src/app/components/checkout/checkout.component.ts(1572,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'affirm'.`

Please can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 0):

add the script to the scripts array in the angular.json file:

```
        "scripts": [
          "src/script.js"
        ]
```

after that, you can use it inside typescript file by declaring a variable for it.

Comment: I already did that one and in that script file having the self invoked functions, I don't know how to declare the variable of the self invoked functions. @ Turzo Ahsan Sami thank you for your reply.